# mysql grouping mre than one query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I try to explain the matter:
I have a hotel management system built with php+mysql. 
I need to extract the number of:

- current reservations visitors
- arriving visitors
- leaving visitors

and I need to know this numbers grouped by "region" (Region is either a country or a region of a country. I get this info from a stored function).
I have tried many times, but I always get values not in line with what I expect.

I have tried grouping by sum, by region, by the two of them, I have tried nesting the queries (horrible result...i'm not that good at subqueries).
Here are the 3 main queries:

Current visitors:

```
select p.num_persone, IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione),getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione, p.*, c.nazione, c.regione from prenota2015 p INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti where p.iddatainizio < 94 and p.iddatafine >= 93 and p.idclienti != '0';
```

Arriving visitors:

```
select p.num_persone, IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione),getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione, p.*, c.nazione, c.regione from prenota2015 p INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti  where p.iddatainizio < 94 and p.iddatainizio >= 93 and p.idclienti != '0';
```

Leaving visitors:

```
select p.num_persone, IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione),getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione, p.*, c.nazione, c.regione from prenota2015 p INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti  where p.iddatafine < 93 and p.iddatafine >= 92 and p.idclienti != '0';
```

The IFNULL stuff checks if it should present the country code or the region code.

Table 'clienti' contains the value of the region or country for IFNULL check mentioned above and it is important for the grouping clause.

what I expect is something like:

```
| region code | visitors present | visitors arriving | visitors leaving
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    219      |      3           |         1         |       1         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    186      |      2           |         0         |       0         |
```

and so on.
Question time: I would you do it?

I tried last time with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione),getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione, 
pres.presenze, 
part.partenze, 
arr.arrivi 
FROM 
(
    select COUNT(p.idprenota) partenze, p.idclienti 
    from prenota2015 p 
    INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti 
    where 
        p.iddatafine < 91 
        and p.iddatafine >= 90 
        GROUP BY regione
) as part, 
(
    select COUNT(p2.idprenota) arrivi, p2.idclienti 
    from prenota2015 p2 
    INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p2.idclienti 
    where 
        p2.iddatainizio < 91 
        and p2.iddatainizio >= 90 
        GROUP BY regione
) as arr, 
(
    select COUNT(p3.idprenota) presenze, p3.idclienti 
    from prenota2015 p3 
    INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p3.idclienti 
    where 
        p3.iddatainizio < 91 
        and p3.iddatafine >= 90
        GROUP BY regione
) as pres, 
clienti c
```

but it was a desperate attempt to try to understand how to move around it.

Any help? Suggestions?

Thank you very much

Comment: do your three individual queries work correctly and give you the desired result? and can you show sample output from those queries?

Comment: I would use views for your problem.

Comment: @pala_ yes the queries work fine. here is an example or real data:
`|245|3717|91|92|k| |1|NULL|NULL|-90|242|NULL|NULL|10|NULL|NULL|ngdz|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|2015-03-31 21:08:48||2015-04-01 08:38:03|1|Russia|NULL`
Another row

`|241|3629|92|92|k| |2|NULL|NULL|-35|137|NULL|NULL|10|NULL|NULL|mteq|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|2015-03-22 18:01:07|2015-03-29 20:13:51|1|Svizzera|`

Comment: the first number of each row you see is region code (245 and 241)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q1.regione,
    q1.total AS current_visitors,
    q2.total AS arriving_visitors,
    q1.total AS leaving_visitors
FROM (
    SELECT sum(p.num_persone) total,
        IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione), getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione    
    FROM prenota2015 p
    INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti
    WHERE p.iddatainizio < 94
        AND p.iddatafine >= 93
        AND p.idclienti != '0'
    GROUP BY regione
    ) q1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sum(p.num_persone) total,
        IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione), getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione
    FROM prenota2015 p
    INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti
    WHERE p.iddatainizio < 94
        AND p.iddatainizio >= 93
        AND p.idclienti != '0'
    GROUP BY regione
    ) q2 ON q1.regione = q2.regione
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sum(p.num_persone) total,
        IFNULL(getcoderegione(c.regione), getNazioneCodeIstat(c.nazione)) regione
    FROM prenota2015 p
    INNER JOIN clienti c ON c.idclienti = p.idclienti
    WHERE p.iddatafine < 93
        AND p.iddatafine >= 92
        AND p.idclienti != '0'
    GROUP BY regione
    ) q3 ON q1.regione = q3.regione;
```

or, as moo suggested, create views of your three queries, which would make this one a lot neater

Comment: I think I cannot create views beacuse the number you see (93, 94, 95) are programmatically changing. I suppose I should end up creating a procedure. Or what?

Comment: views would simply make this query easier to look at :)

Comment: I was trying your solution, but I get this error: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'num_persone'

Comment: I think we are closer to the goal :)

Comment: I thought you said your queries worked? I just copy pasted them in there. let me edit out what i think is the error. It was asking for p.num_persone AND p.* in each subquery. I got rid of all the columns you dont seem to be interested in. try now

Comment: I made some correction (you wrote persons instead of persone and left a comma after "regione" in the FROM clause. I don't get sums of the persons grouped by regione, sadly :( Very tough this one for me

Comment: oh sorry, i thought for some reason your queries were returning grouped data. two secs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74438/discussion-between-pala-and-aptivus).